# Tomato 1.25 router administration using SSH fails with publickey error

Tags: ssh, tomato

I'm trying to get ssh up and running on a router running Tomato.

I just generated a new public key using

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

and everything went as expected. Typed in a passphrase, told me it was saved.

I copied that resulting id_rsa.pub contents into Tomato so that it now looks like this:

[image]

When I try to connect I get the following error:

```
$ ssh 10.10.10.1
Permission denied (publickey).
```

First time trying to do this with Tomato. Any thoughts?

FWIW, I'm trying to make it so that I can test sites I'm developing on my MacBook using name based VirtualHosts to work on my iPad for testing following [this sort of advice](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2008/tomato-reverse-dns/). Any suggestions in that department would be welcome, as well.

Comment: Try connecting with ssh root@10.10.10.1 instead.

Comment: @CGA: That did it. Could you answer the question so I can accept your solution, maybe with some background about why you need the `root@` prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As CGA correctly asserts, you need to specify the user that you wish to log in as. If you don't do this, you will essentially be trying to log in as the current local user on the remote machine. In other words, if you're logged in as *rune* on your local computer, and you try to log in via ssh on the remote machine using this command:

```
rune@runescomp:~$ ssh 192.168.2.1
```

it will be equivalent to the following command:

```
rune@runescomp:~$ ssh rune@192.168.2.1
```

which will get rejected unless there's a user named *rune* on the remote machine.

Comment: can you add the root example, since that's the real answer here. Tomato doesn't make it very clear in their config webpages that the user will be root. In fact I was trying `ssh admin@192.168.1.1` as I login to the router with the admin user.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same problem except that I was already using `ssh root@192.168.1.1`.  I tried all sorts of stuff and went over my instructions over and over.  I came to find out that there is a bug in Ubuntu (the system I was using to connect) that has been present for many, many versions which causes this problem.  The solution was simply to type `ssh-add` from the Ubuntu client and enter the same pass phrase (or lack thereof) that was entered before.  BAM!  Instant access!

I just thought I would add that in case folks found this thread while searching for a solution (as I did).

HTH,
Billy